# How do I get the annotation value 'used'

Tags: groovy, annotations

I want to retrieve the annotation value `used` from `MyAnnot`. I am getting 3 annotations in the list even though there are only 2. Also, I have  tried obtaining the `used` field of `MyAnnot` but with no success. I would like to return a map where `MyAnnot`'s  `used` is the key and `type` as the map's value.

```
// Then, define your class with it's annotated Fields
class MyClass {
   @MyAnnot(used = "Hey", type = "There")
   String fielda

   @MyAnnot(used = "denn", type = "Ton") 
   String fieldc
}

def findAllPropertiesForClassWithAnotation(obj, annotClass) {
   def op = []
   def annos = []
   def i = 0
   obj.properties.findAll { prop ->
      obj.getClass().declaredFields.find { 
         it.name == prop.key && annotClass in it.declaredAnnotations*.annotationType()
         annos=it.declaredAnnotations
         i++
         if(annos)
         op << annos[0] as Set
      // println"Props ${annos[0]}"
      }
   }
   op.each{ println "${it} and i is ${i}"}
}

// Then, define an instance of our class
MyClass a = new MyClass(fielda: 'tim', fieldc: 'dennisStar')

// And print the results of calling our method
println findAllPropertiesForClassWithAnotation(a, MyAnnot)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to mark you annotation with: `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)` to make it available for processing at runtime, so it will be:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface MyAnnot {
    String used()
    String type()
}
```

Then, `used` and `type` are not fields, nor properties but *methods*, so they must be *invoked* and *get*.

The script will be:

```
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy
import java.lang.annotation.Retention

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface MyAnnot {
    String used()
    String type()
}

class MyClass {
    @MyAnnot(used="Hey" ,type="There")
    String fielda

    @MyAnnot(used="denn", type="Ton") 
    String fieldc
}

def findAllPropertiesForClassWithAnotation( obj, annotClass ) {
    def c = obj.getClass()
    c.declaredFields.findAll { field ->
        field.isAnnotationPresent(annotClass)
    }.collect { found ->
        def a = found.getAnnotation(annotClass)
        [(a.used()): a.type()]
    }.sum()
}

MyClass a = new MyClass(fielda: 'tim', fieldc: 'dennisStar')

println findAllPropertiesForClassWithAnotation(a, MyAnnot)
```

Mind that passing only a class of annotation is not sufficient, since you don't know the methods (`used` and `type`) to be invoked on the annotation. The following method will work only for `MyAnnot` class.